# What's the command that Ctrl-Q triggers on VSCode (Windows)

Tags: visual-studio-code

On Windows VSCode `ctrl+q` shows a menu with the items on the activity bar.

What is that command?

I switch to Linux and want to add a key binding to that command (not map by default as on Linux `ctrl+q` quits the program) but cannot find it and don't have a Windows machine at hand to look on the key bindings and doesn't seem to be listed [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### When we do *not* have access to VSC on given platform

It should be possible to sift through the sources.

In this case we are looking for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> that should be `CtrlCmd` and <kbd>Q</kbd> `KeyQ` in `KEYBINDING` of some module class, so something like:

```
    static readonly ID = 'workbench.action.quickOpenView';
    static readonly KEYBINDING = {
        primary: KeyMod.CtrlCmd | KeyCode.KeyQ,
        mac: { primary: KeyMod.WinCtrl | KeyCode.KeyQ },
        linux: { primary: 0 }
    };
```

(Yes, that's exactly it and I've started from here backwards.)

Slightly convoluted GitHub search query *

> [`KEYBINDING KeyMod CtrlCmd KeyCode KeyQ repo:microsoft/vscode extension:ts`](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Amicrosoft%2Fvscode+extension%3Ats+KEYBINDING+KeyMod+CtrlCmd+KeyCode+KeyQ&type=Code)

should bring us [there](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/cdfee234401539007f33c87ae0c80b2b5304d381/src/vs/workbench/contrib/quickaccess/browser/viewQuickAccess.ts#L213-L217) so we now have the command `ID`: `workbench.action.quickOpenView`.

---

#### When we *have* VSC on platform at hand

It is easy as using the *'Record keys'* feature in the *Keyboard Shortcuts* settings pane to find this information (either clicking the "Keyboard" icon or using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) where we should find that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> is by default bound to *View: Quick Open View*:

[image: Visual Studio Code - Keyboard Shortcuts settings page with filter set to "ctrl+q" and "Recording Keys" toggle active; results show relevant bindings]

---

- GitHub code search sadly [ignores all non-alphanumerics](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-code#considerations-for-code-search)

  . , : ; / \ ` ' " = * ! ? # $ & + ^ | ~ < > ( ) { } [ ] @

Comment: Overlooked that "I don't have a Windows machine at hand" completely X|
I've added solution pattern that could hopefully work in such scenario, though admittedly I would not figure that if I didn't know what to look for.

Answer (score -1):

Little late to party but you need to set a custom key binding to `workbench.action.quit` for windows operating system to exit all instance of vscode at once.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the suggestion, but the question was not related to exit all instance of vscode at once, neither how to do it on windows. And it already was solved, more than 2 years ago!